# Converting a list to a list of list

Tags: c#, linq

Is there an elegant way to convert a list to a list of list?

```
int colCount = 2;
int rowCount = 5;
var src = new List<double>(colCount * rowCount);
var dst = new List<List<double>>(rowCount);
// dst <- src, the elegant way
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood you right, you have `src` `List<double>` with `colCount * rowCount`

```
 var src = new List<double>(colCount * rowCount);

 src.Add(...);
 ...
 src.Add(...);
```

and you want to *convert* `src` into *rectangular* `List<List<double>>` (`rowCount` items `colCount` values in each). If it's your case

```
 var dst = src
   .Select((item, index) => (item, index))
   .GroupBy(pair => pair.index / rowCount, pair => pair.item)
   .Select(group => group.ToList())
   .ToList();
```

If you want just to *create* `dst` and fill it with some value (let it be `0.0`):

```
var dst = Enumerable
  .Range(0, rowCount)
  .Select(r => Enumerable
     .Range(0, colCount)
     .Select(c => 0.0)
     .ToList())
  .ToList();
```